# Retrofit 2.0 throwing "IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding". How to do right API query and fix it?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

My problem is that **I don't know how to start using Retrofit 2.0 with received API** - mentioned below...

Firstly, I need to username, password, fbID (optional), gmailID (optional), twitID (optional), gender, birthDate, location (not required - if long and lat has values), longitude (optional), latitude (optional), profileImage (optional).

When all parameters are good - receive `status = true`. 
If not - receive `status = false` and required parameters which are wrong (e.g. mail is already taken)

So I can receive 
`status = true` 
or 
`status = false` and array with max 5 parameters (username, email, password, gender, birthDate).

I tried this `API Interface`:

```
public interface AuthRegisterUserApi {
    @PUT()
    Call<AuthRegisterUserModel> getStatus(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("fbID") String fbID,
            @Field("gmailID") String gmailID,
            @Field("twitID") String twitID,
            @Field("gender") String gender,
            @Field("birthDate") String birthDate,
            @Field("location") String location,
            @Field("longitude") String longitude,
            @Field("latitude") String latitude,
            @Field("profileImage") String profileImage
            );

    class Factory {
        private static AuthRegisterUserApi service;

        public static AuthRegisterUserApi getInstance() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApiConstants.REGISTER_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            service = retrofit.create(AuthRegisterUserApi.class);

            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

[with this API models (Pastebin.com)](http://pastebin.com/7X5D0NjL)

and this code in `Activity`:

```
AuthRegisterUserApi.Factory.getInstance()
        .getStatus(
                usernameEditText.getText().toString(),
                emailEditText.getText().toString(),
                passwordEditText.getText().toString(),
                "", "", "",
                (maleRadioButton.isChecked() ? "male" : "female"),
                mYear + "-" + mMonth+1 + "-" + mDay,
                (geoLocationToggleButton.isChecked() ? geoLocationEditText.getText().toString() : ""),
                (!geoLocationToggleButton.isChecked() ? "50" : ""),
                (!geoLocationToggleButton.isChecked() ? "50" : ""),
                "")
        .enqueue(new Callback<AuthRegisterUserModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AuthRegisterUserModel> call, Response<AuthRegisterUserModel> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.body().isStatus()) {
                showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Registration ok.");
            } else {
                response.body().getInfo().getUsername();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<AuthRegisterUserModel> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

I have error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1) for method AuthRegisterUserApi.getStatus`

I tried to register user using Postman and it works when I used option `Body` -> `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**How can I create I `register` query to this API?** Change `@Field` to something else? I have got this error always...

**EDIT: Need to change `API Interface` to this**:

```
public interface AuthRegisterUserApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("/api/register")
    Call<AuthRegisterUserModel> getStatus(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("fbID") String fbID,
            @Field("gmailID") String gmailID,
            @Field("twitID") String twitID,
            @Field("gender") String gender,
            @Field("birthDate") String birthDate,
            @Field("location") String location,
            @Field("longitude") String longitude,
            @Field("latitude") String latitude,
            @Field("profileImage") String profileImage
            );

    class Factory {
        private static AuthRegisterUserApi service;

        public static AuthRegisterUserApi getInstance() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            service = retrofit.create(AuthRegisterUserApi.class);

            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

`BASE_URL = http://ip_address:8400` for me...

But still got error: `Response.rawResponse = Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://ip_address:8400/api/register}`. Using Postman with the same data I received code=201 Created. **Don't know why...**

Comment: Try to change `@Field` to `@Query`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier `IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @PUT URL or @Url parameter. for method AuthRegisterUserApi.getStatus` and my `REGISTER_URL = BASE_URL + "register/";`

Comment: Can i see the all URL ? And you can try to keep `@Field` and add above `@PUT`, `@FormUrlEncoded`

Comment: `BASE_URL = http://ip_address:8400/api/`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier The same error (`Missing either @PUT URL or @Url parameter. for method AuthRegisterUserApi.getStatus`) with `@Field` and `@FormUrlEncoded` above `@PUT`

Comment: Yeah, you to add the endpoint into `@PUT()`, your `BASE_URL` should be just `http://ip_address:8400` and your endpoints in PUT, should be `@PUT("/api/register")`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier tried to change it and using `@Field` but received false in `response.isSuccesful()`. When I removed this part got error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.app.models.api.auth.RegisterModel.isStatus()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Check the code response, he is in response, normally, when it's not 200 or 201, you received a wrong response, so your body is NULL.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier got `code 400` and `response.body() = null` but doing this (with the same parameters) in Postman got `code 201 created` (and ofc received `status = true`)

Comment: In Postman your are in mode `PUT` and your argument are in `body -> x-www-form-urlencoded` ? Can you edit your post, with the new things we change ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Yes, my args are in `body -> x-www-form-urlencoded`. Edited.

Comment: Oh i see, i will post an answer in few minutes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was because I try to `PUT` e.g. `longitude` \ `latitude` \ `location` with no value - empty `String`.

I mean - there was a problem on API side. So to avoid that I changed method to this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT(ApiConstants.REGISTER_URL_PART)
Call<RegisterModel> registerUser(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("fbID") String fbID,
        @Field("gmailID") String gmailID,
        @Field("twitID") String twitID,
        @Field("gender") String gender,
        @Field("birthDate") String birthDate,
        @Nullable @Field("location") String location,
        @Nullable @Field("longitude") String longitude,
        @Nullable @Field("latitude") String latitude,
        @Field("profileImage") String profileImage
);
```

Now, when I go no value for one of them, I simply don't enclose this field.

Answer (score 85):

you just missed `@FormUrlEncoded` above your Rest method call.

Answer (score 57):

Your request is not encoded right, but are postman, so do change that :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("/api/register")
    Call<AuthRegisterUserModel> getStatus(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("fbID") String fbID,
            @Field("gmailID") String gmailID,
            @Field("twitID") String twitID,
            @Field("gender") String gender,
            @Field("birthDate") String birthDate,
            @Field("location") String location,
            @Field("longitude") String longitude,
            @Field("latitude") String latitude,
            @Field("profileImage") String profileImage);
```

Tell me if it's ok.

Comment: `Response.rawResponse = Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://ip_address:8400/api/register}`. Co this is not working.

Comment: You are sure, that your request is a put and not a post ?

Comment: Have try with a different arguments ? Because since you put him in the database you can't reput him ?

Comment: Trying with different params on app first - response null; on Postman - response `status = true`. Mindblow...

Comment: Okay, that's weird, on postman the endpoint is register/ or register ?

Comment: `register`, without slash "/"

Comment: `POST` method is working. But `PUT` method is working when I removed `response.isStatus()` from `onResponse() method`... Trying to change status to String, still response null when using `response.isStatus()`...

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error message and I noticed that in my interface definition I missed the @ForUrlEncoded annotation - on top of the rest call that will use the form part, which seems to be the same thing you did at the first posted code block. Take a look at it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You saved me, man!!! Thanks a ton.By mistake, I deleted this line and was facing this error.