# How to upload photo in android retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit

I can't upload photo to server. **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)**. Please help me, how to solve or any other suggestions. [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8FLX.png)

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@Multipart
@POST("qq/api/xxxx")
Call<Custom> postCustom(@Field("Id") String Id,
   @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
   @Field("Status") String Status);
```

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994301/retrofit-2-0-throwing-illegalargumentexception-field-parameters-can-only-be-u

Answer (score 0):

**Change your request interface like this**

```java
@Multipart
@POST("qq/api/xxxx")
Call<Custom> postCustom(
   @Part("Id") String Id,
   @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
   @Part("Status") String Status);
```

You cannot use both `@FormUrlEncoded` and `@Multipart` on a single method since an HTTP request can only have one `Content-Type`. `@FormUrlEncoded` and `@Multipart` are both content types.

From **Jake Wharton**

> You can have to use `FormUrlEncodedTypedOutput` as a `@Part` argument for the form encoded part and build it up yourself. The annotation on the method is for the outermost encoding which in this case is multipart.

**References**

I have added also these issue reference which is really helpful for you to understanding what you are about to change in your http request method

- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/662
- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1210

Comment: How to call from Activity? **Call<Custom> postCustom( , , )**

Comment: I only based my answer based on the error message you provided. Just in case, do you have `AsyncTask` or `RxJava` setup? You may be needing some asynchronous libraries for you to call that http method in the background.