# when I click my recycler view item then my app will be crashed

Tags: android, json, post, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Here My app Wil be Crashing When I click my Recycler view Item and display the data in to  another recycler view, but here is some error will be generated.
how can I solve this error if anyone can have idea please tell.

[show error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IruYL.png)

here is my code.
**ApiInterface.java**

```
  @POST("api/student_point")
    Call<courseinfo>getdetails(@Field("id")String id);
```

**CoureseD.java**

```
public void processing(){
            progresshandler.show();
            Call<courseinfo>call=apiInterface.getdetails("1");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<courseinfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<courseinfo> call, Response<courseinfo> response) {
                    courseinfo courseinfo=response.body();
                    Log.i("Response",String.valueOf(courseinfo.getMessage()));
                    boolean mSuccess = false;
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
    
                        if(response.body()!=null){
                            if(response.body().getStatus().equals("success"))
                            {
                                mSuccess=true;
                                if(mSuccess) {
    
                                    settel(response.body().getBlogs());
                                    progresshandler.hide();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                                }
                            }
    
                        }
    
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<courseinfo> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progresshandler.hide();
                }
            });
        } 
       private void settel(ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog> blogs) {
           coureseadapter coureseadapter = new coureseadapter(blogs, context);
           coureseview.setAdapter(coureseadapter);
    
       }
```

**coureseadapter.java**

```
public class coureseadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<coureseadapter.coureseviewholder>{


    private ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog>blogs;
    private Context context;

    public coureseadapter(ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog> blogs, Context context) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public coureseviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.coureseinfo,parent,false);
        return new coureseviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull coureseviewholder holder, int position) {


       // holder.point.setText(blogs.get(position).getId());
        holder.point.setText(blogs.get(position).getPoint());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blogs.size();
    }

    class coureseviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CheckBox ch;
        TextView point;
        Spinner fact;

        public coureseviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ch=itemView.findViewById(R.id.c_d);

            point=itemView.findViewById(R.id.point_n);
            fact=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fac_n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to google for your error ? ... There is already answer here ... Please, do internet search before asking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2.0 throwing "IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding". How to do right API query and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994301/retrofit-2-0-throwing-illegalargumentexception-field-parameters-can-only-be-u)

Comment: @Nitish I already show This Type Of Articles but didn't not solve my problem..

Comment: Adding `@FormUrlEncoded` , are you still getting the same error or some other error

Comment: @Nitish after adding (@FormUrlEncoded)still getting error.. something like no response body

Comment: Check your api in Postman . if you are using the correct api url with correct params or not

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error point to this issue only
add `FormUrlEncoded` Above your call

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/student_point")
Call<courseinfo> getdetails(@Field("id") String id);
```